# Div is not taking full width

Tags: html, css

**html code :**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="style/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


<!-- div for box-->
<div id="panel"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS used :**

```
#panel
{
    height:90px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;    

}
```

**Output generateed: is a box with space left around it of 4-5pxs, and it does not cover full width.:**

**Expected output: with no spaces around it what i really want to do:**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to clear the default margin that gets applied to the body. add:

```
body{ 
  margin: 0; 
}
```